# Java Size of Sending Class Objects

Tags: java, class, sockets, serialization

I am making a program that needs to send data over the internet about which classes will need to be used. I am planning on doing this by sending an array of classes like this:
`Class<? extends Unit>[] classes`
These class files are on the server and client ends of the program. **Is it appropriate to send the classes over the internet?** I am scared it will send the class and all of its data to describe it rather than just a pointer to a class.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about serialization?

Comment: Yes Serialization using Object input and output streams, sorry

Comment: *I am scared it will send the class and all of its data to describe it rather than just a pointer to a class.*  - be very scared

Comment: A pointer to *what?* To be resolved how? *Of course* it will send the class. But the real issue is that the class won't be any use to you at the receiver unless it has been loaded by a classloader. You can't just acquire classes via Serialization. Are you looking for the RMI Codebase feature? And what does all this have to do with your title?

Comment: I am just wondering if it uses a lot of data or not to send Classes over object streams, or does it use an insane amount of data trying to actually describe the blueprint of the class rather than just a name of which class to look at (Since both the client and server already have the blueprint of all the classes)

Comment: How much space it takes is irrelevant, as it won't work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not send the code of the classes though. You must either provide the class files on the remote machine, or transfer them as byte[].